# Can we use redux actions inside a function that is not a functional component or a class component in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

Hello I would like to know if and how it is possible to use and implement redux actions that are not inside a class or functional component.

I would like to implement something like this.

```
import { setPerson } from ./actions.js

export const registerPerson = (data) => {
  /* here we do whatever we need to set register a person */

   ... 
   .then((res) => {
     setPerson(res.data). <--- Here is the instance that I want to do.
   }).catch(err => console.warn(err);

}
```

The goal would be to import the `registerPerson` function into a React component where the redux actions will fire within the imported function.

Comment: yes..possible. You can store the reference to dispatch on a global obj or on a Class as a static property and use it where ever you want. But not recommended unless you have no other option.

Comment: Good one is to pass the dispatch as an argument from the component or function that calls this `registerPerson` and then dispatch it using that argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call your actions in `then` methods of something request to back-end. But make sure, that you should **dispatch** you action.

Comment: what do you mean by dispatch ? @Valentin

Comment: @jaffer_syed disptach is a function used to run your action so that reducer can update the store based on your action